# USB device not going through VM?

Tags: virtualization, usb

I have a server (we'll call it Server01, Win2008R2) that has a Virtual Environment (also a Win 2008R2 Environment) ran through Hyper-V.

I have a program on the VM that needs an USB Device (it's actually a small USB scale).

When plugging the USB device into Server01 it does not show on the Virtual Environment (I have a program that it needs to be used on).

Now lets pretend this USB device HAS to be checked on this Virtual Environment, is there any way to allow the Virtual Environment to see the USB device like it's been plugged in?

Comment: USB passthrough is not natively supported by Hyper-V, and quite frankly, is unlikely to be given that a Hyper-V platform is normally built up around the premise of being highly available. Passing USB devices from a single physical host machine through to a Virtual Machine is not in keeping with that general design premise! There are various workarounds involving either USB network hubs or custom add-ons for Hyper-V which provide this emulation; your favourite search engine should be able to locate such hardware/software tools for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native support but still a few options...

1. Software USB redirectors - questionable reliability and requires software installed on the server
2. Network USB hub - expensive and device compatibility issues
3. VMWare does USB passthrough, convert your server and VM to that